# Deploy Eureka Server & Client on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, netflix-eureka

I want to deploy eureka server on kubernetes, and want to specify the service name to the clients , so that whenever any client wants to connect to eureka server , it should do it using the service name of eureka server.

Comment: Consider providing more information about the problem you are facing. refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look up how you would do it in Docker and adapt those instructions.

Comment: @Ubercool , the main problem i am facing is that i am unable to register the clients to eureka server using the service name .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the official images for Eureka haven’t been updated in years, so I think you’re on your own and will have to work this out from scratch. There are a few Helm charts but they all seem to reference private images and are pretty simple so not sure how much that will help.